# Implementing __call__ function in MyBasicLSTMCell in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I have a weird problem with my code. I am trying to implement the `__call__` function on `BasicLSTMCell`. Here is the problem. I have the following code.

```
def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    c, h = array_ops.split(1, 2, state)
    #bbb = tf.concat(1,[inputs,h])
    matrix = tf.get_variable("W", [320, 80])
    concat = tf.matmul(tf.concat(1,[inputs,h]), matrix)

    i, j, f, o = array_ops.split(1, 4, concat)
    new_c = c * sigmoid(f + self._forget_bias) + sigmoid(i) * tanh(j)
    new_h = tanh(new_c) * sigmoid(o)
    return new_h, array_ops.concat(1, [new_c, new_h])
```

In the above code, variable `bbb` is not being used anywhere. And suprisingly depending on whether I comment it or not, I get different outputs. Weird. What is more weird is that when I move the `bbb` variable after the `matrix` variable, the difference goes away. This means that irrespective of comment, I get the same output.

Comment: How different are the outputs? Can you link the whole code as well?